# Show div when all fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to show a div when all inputs are filled , but unfortunately it shows nothing here is my JS , it works on the JS FIDDLE but not on the website

```
$('#name, #prenom, #password,#confirm_password, #email,#confirm_email').bind('keyup', function() {
    if(allFilled())  $('.next2').show();
});

function allFilled() {
    var filled = true;
    $('body input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') filled = false;
    });
    return filled;
}
```

Comment: `, it works on the JS FIDDLE but not on the website`  then, how could we debug it ? Also, why you 'assume' that the inputs are by default '  filled ' ( with value ) ?

Comment: can you link the Fiddle?

Comment: @MoPaMo OP is supposed to add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not a link to an external resource that might not be available or change over time.

Comment: If it works in the fiddle and not on the website then you have script conflicts or some errors. Check your console tab.

Comment: _"As of jQuery 3.0, [`.bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged."_

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the jQuery collection [into an an array](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) and then use the native JS array method [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check to see if all the inputs contain values.

```js
const inputs = $('input');

inputs.on('keyup', function() {

  const notEmpty = inputs.toArray().every(input => {
    return input.value !== '';
  });

  if (notEmpty) {
    $('div').show();
  } else {
    $('div').hide();
  }

});
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
<div>All the values!</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this , but I have changed the code to this so I can use a class.   const inputs = $('input');

inputs.on('keyup', function() {

  const notEmpty = inputs.toArray().every(input => {
    return input.value !== '';
  });

  if (notEmpty) {
    $('#next2').show();
  } else {
    $('#next2').hide();
  }

});   ; and still doesnt work